# Does _control87() also set the SSE MXCSR Control Register?

Tags: visual-c++, sse, msvcrt, crt, fpu

The documentation for [`_control87`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) notes:

> `_control87` [...] affect[s] the control words for both the x87 and the SSE2, if present.

It seems that the SSE and SSE2 MXCSR control registers are identical, however, there is no mention of the SSE unit in the documentation. Does `_control87` affect an SSE unit's MXCSR control register or is this only true for SSE2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug out an old Pentium III and checked with the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] ) {
    using namespace std;

    // Unmask all SSE/SSE2 exceptions
    _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK( 0 );
    // Get SSE/SSE2 exception mask
    DWORD dwExceptionMask = _MM_GET_EXCEPTION_MASK();
    cout << "Exception Mask: 0x" << hex << setw( 8 )
         << setfill( '0' ) << dwExceptionMask << endl;

    // Mask all FPU exceptions
    _control87( 0xFFFF, _MCW_EM );

    // Get SSE/SSE2 exception mask
    dwExceptionMask = _MM_GET_EXCEPTION_MASK();
    cout << "Exception Mask: 0x" << hex << setw( 8 )
         << setfill( '0' ) << dwExceptionMask << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result on Pentium III (SSE):

```
Exception Mask: 0x00000000
Exception Mask: 0x00000000
```

Result on Xeon (SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3):

```
Exception Mask: 0x00000000
Exception Mask: 0x00001e80
```

The results are surprising, but in line with the documentation. `_control87` only has an effect on the MXCSR control register if at least an SSE2 unit is available.

Answer (score 0):

One MXCSR controls both sse and sse2 (and sse3 and ssse3 and sse4.1 and ...)

Comment: Thanks for the information. This would actually be all the more reason for the `_control87` function to behave identically across all SSE implementations. Surprisingly, it doesn't.

Comment: I assume that this is because MSVC doesn’t target SSE for fp codegen unless SSE2 is also available.

Comment: MSVC offers both `/arch:SSE` and `/arch:SSE2` compiler switches to control the availability of instruction sets when optimizing FP code. It does generate SSE (i.e. purely single precision) floating point code, if the `/arch:SSE` switch is use alongside any of the optimization options.

Comment: I’d be lying if I said that this was the first time that MSVC’s numerics model left me stumped.  Very interesting.