# Recovering context after handling exception only works with VS /RTCs (run time checks) enabled

Tags: floating-point, structured-exception

My end goal here is to provide a means to catch a floating-point exception, print a stack trace, and resume execution with floating point exceptions disabled (using the resulting non-finite/not-a-number values).  I've progressed a bit since my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590408/configuring-floating-point-unit-context-in-win32-vs-win64), in which I realized that there's more registers that need to be adjusted to clear/configure the floating-point unit when using SSE (default in x64).

I did get a working very simple example, however things are falling apart for x64 once I go to a release build.  Debug/Release build works fine against an x86 target.   I've narrowed the issue down to the ["Run-Time-Checks" option of Visual-Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx), specifically RTCs, which "Enables stack frame run-time error checking".

Here's the example program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <float.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

double zero = 0.0;

void printException(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionInfo){
    bool bFloatingPointRecoverFlag = false;
    switch(ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode)
    {
        case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_INEXACT_RESULT:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_INEXACT_RESULT\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW\n", stderr);
            bFloatingPointRecoverFlag = 1;
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_INVALID_DISPOSITION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP\n", stderr);
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW:
            fputs(" EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW\n", stderr);
            break;
        default:
            fputs(" Unrecognized Exception\n", stderr);
            break;
    }
}

LONG WINAPI myfunc(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionInfo){
    printf("#########Caught Ya:");
    printException(ExceptionInfo);
    printf("ExceptionAddr = 0x%p\n",ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);

    /* clear the exception */
    unsigned int stat = _clearfp();

    /* disable fp exceptions*/
    unsigned int ctrlwrd;
    errno_t err =  _controlfp_s(&ctrlwrd, _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM);

    /* Disable and clear the exceptions in the exception context */
    #if _WIN64
        /* Get current context to get the values of MxCsr register, which was
         * set by the calls to _controlfp above, we need to copy these into
         * the exception context so that exceptions really stay disabled.
         * References:
         *    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxty7t75.aspx
         *    https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz
         */
        _CONTEXT myContext;
        GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread(),&myContext);

        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FltSave.ControlWord = ctrlwrd;
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FltSave.StatusWord = 0;
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FltSave.MxCsr = myContext.FltSave.MxCsr;
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FltSave.MxCsr_Mask = myContext.FltSave.MxCsr_Mask;
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->MxCsr = myContext.MxCsr;
    #else
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FloatSave.ControlWord = ctrlwrd;
        ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->FloatSave.StatusWord = 0;
    #endif

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double e;

    /* do something so that zero can't get optimized */
    if(argc > 999999){
        zero = (double) argc;
    }


    /* Enable fp exceptions */
    _controlfp_s(0, 0, _MCW_EM);

    /* Setup our unhandled exception filter */
   SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(myfunc);

    b = 5.0+zero;

    /* do something bad */
    a = 5.0 / zero;

    c = a * b;

    e = 5.0 / zero;

    d = 4.0 + e;

    printf("a = %f\n",a);
    printf("b = %f\n",b);
    printf("c = %f\n",c);
    printf("d = %f\n",d);
    printf("e = %f\n",e);

    return 0;
}
```

With RTCs ENABLED, this code creates output (which is what I expect):

```
#########Caught Ya: EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO
ExceptionAddr = 0x000000013F7A1638
a = 1.#INF00
b = 5.000000
c = 1.#INF00
d = 1.#INF00
e = 1.#INF00
```

With RTCs DISABLED, this code creates output:

```
#########Caught Ya: EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO
ExceptionAddr = 0x000000013F0415F2
#########Caught Ya: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
ExceptionAddr = 0x000000007711B519
#########Caught Ya: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
ExceptionAddr = 0x000000007711B519
#########Caught Ya: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
ExceptionAddr = 0x000000007711B519
.... repeat forever
```

So, in summary:

- against x86 target (WIN32): No Problems in with either debug or release builds!
- against x64 target (WIN64): Access violation occurs after attempting to recover from floating point exception, only when RTCs DISABLED.

Any thoughts on what RTCs does, and why it would affect the behavior of recovering from an floating point exception?

EDIT:
I've debugged this a bit further in assembly.  The violation occurs after returning from the filter-function, but before resuming at the divide-by-zero.  Below is the assembly leading up to the access violation (the last line of assembly is the culprit):

```
000000007711B2EF  mov         dword ptr [rcx+0F0h],edi  
000000007711B2F5  fxsave      [rcx+100h]  
000000007711B2FC  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1A0h],xmm0  
000000007711B303  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1B0h],xmm1  
000000007711B30A  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1C0h],xmm2  
000000007711B311  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1D0h],xmm3  
000000007711B318  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1E0h],xmm4  
000000007711B31F  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+1F0h],xmm5  
000000007711B326  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+200h],xmm6  
000000007711B32D  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+210h],xmm7  
000000007711B334  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+220h],xmm8  
000000007711B33C  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+230h],xmm9  
000000007711B344  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+240h],xmm10  
000000007711B34C  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+250h],xmm11  
000000007711B354  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+260h],xmm12  
000000007711B35C  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+270h],xmm13  
000000007711B364  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+280h],xmm14  
000000007711B36C  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+290h],xmm15  
000000007711B374  stmxcsr     dword ptr [rcx+34h]  
000000007711B378  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+8]  
000000007711B37D  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0F8h],rax  
000000007711B384  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp]  
000000007711B387  mov         dword ptr [rcx+44h],eax  
000000007711B38A  mov         dword ptr [rcx+30h],10000Fh  
000000007711B391  add         rsp,8  
000000007711B395  ret  
000000007711B396  int         3  
000000007711B397  int         3  
000000007711B398  int         3  
000000007711B399  int         3  
000000007711B39A  int         3  
000000007711B39B  int         3  
000000007711B39C  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000007711B39F  push        rbp  
000000007711B3A0  push        rsi  
000000007711B3A1  push        rdi  
000000007711B3A2  sub         rsp,30h  
000000007711B3A6  mov         rbp,rsp  
000000007711B3A9  test        rdx,rdx  
000000007711B3AC  je          000000007711B4E4  
000000007711B3B2  cmp         dword ptr [rdx],80000029h  
000000007711B3B8  jne         000000007711B3C4  
000000007711B3BA  cmp         dword ptr [rdx+18h],1  
000000007711B3BE  jae         000000007711B634  
000000007711B3C4  cmp         dword ptr [rdx],80000026h  
000000007711B3CA  jne         000000007711B4E4  
000000007711B3D0  mov         rax,qword ptr [rdx+20h]  
000000007711B3D4  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+8]  
000000007711B3D8  mov         qword ptr [rcx+90h],r8  
000000007711B3DF  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+10h]  
000000007711B3E3  mov         qword ptr [rcx+98h],r8  
000000007711B3EA  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+18h]  
000000007711B3EE  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0A0h],r8  
000000007711B3F5  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+20h]  
000000007711B3F9  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0A8h],r8  
000000007711B400  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+28h]  
000000007711B404  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0B0h],r8  
000000007711B40B  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+30h]  
000000007711B40F  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0D8h],r8  
000000007711B416  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+38h]  
000000007711B41A  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0E0h],r8  
000000007711B421  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+40h]  
000000007711B425  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0E8h],r8  
000000007711B42C  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+48h]  
000000007711B430  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0F0h],r8  
000000007711B437  mov         r8,qword ptr [rax+50h]  
000000007711B43B  mov         qword ptr [rcx+0F8h],r8  
000000007711B442  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rax+58h]  
000000007711B446  mov         dword ptr [rcx+34h],r8d  
000000007711B44A  mov         dword ptr [rcx+118h],r8d  
000000007711B451  mov         r8w,word ptr [rax+5Ch]  
000000007711B456  mov         word ptr [rcx+100h],r8w  
000000007711B45E  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+60h]  
000000007711B462  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+200h],xmm0  
000000007711B469  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+70h]  
000000007711B46D  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+210h],xmm0  
000000007711B474  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+80h]  
000000007711B47B  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+220h],xmm0  
000000007711B482  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+90h]  
000000007711B489  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+230h],xmm0  
000000007711B490  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0A0h]  
000000007711B497  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+240h],xmm0  
000000007711B49E  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0B0h]  
000000007711B4A5  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+250h],xmm0  
000000007711B4AC  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0C0h]  
000000007711B4B3  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+260h],xmm0  
000000007711B4BA  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0D0h]  
000000007711B4C1  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+270h],xmm0  
000000007711B4C8  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0E0h]  
000000007711B4CF  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+280h],xmm0  
000000007711B4D6  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rax+0F0h]  
000000007711B4DD  movaps      xmmword ptr [rcx+290h],xmm0  
000000007711B4E4  mov         eax,dword ptr [rcx+30h]  
000000007711B4E7  and         eax,100040h  
000000007711B4EC  cmp         eax,100040h  
000000007711B4F1  jne         000000007711B519  
000000007711B4F3  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rcx+34h]  
000000007711B4F7  movsxd      rax,dword ptr [rcx+4E0h]  
000000007711B4FE  lea         rbx,[rcx+2D0h]  
000000007711B505  add         rbx,rax  
000000007711B508  xchg        r8d,dword ptr [rbx+18h]  
000000007711B50C  mov         eax,0FFFFFFFCh  
000000007711B511  cdq  
000000007711B512  xrstor      [rbx]  
000000007711B515  mov         dword ptr [rbx+18h],r8d  
000000007711B519  fxrstor     [rcx+100h]
```

The value in the debugger of "rcx" is 0x30e340, and the exception message in visual studio reads: "First-chance exception at 0x7711b519 in fptest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff."

Why would VS report that it is attempting to read 0xffffffffffffffff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer to my own question.  I had been using a line `GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread(),&myContext)` to capture the current context, which had my desired values for floating point registers after calling _clearfp and _controlfp.  However I failed to notice in the help for GetThreadContext: **If you call GetThreadContext for the current thread, the function returns successfully; however, the context returned is not valid.**

Turns out the right way to get the current thread context is RtlCaptureContext.  I'll edit my original code to reflect.